# How to stop “Desktop” from appearing under “This PC” in Navigation Pane in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I’m using Windows 10 (Pro x64 v21H1), with “Show all folders” and “Expand to current folder” enabled in the Navigation Pane settings. I’ve also renamed “This PC” to “Computer” just because.

Normally when I open a File Explorer window, either through Ctrl+E or clicking a particular folder on my desktop, the opened folder is displayed/selected normally in the NavPane, like this:

[image: Navigation Pane with no “Desktop” under “This PC”]

However, with some apps that let me browse folders (such as Stardock ObjectDock in this case), opening a folder from there instead displays it under a new “Desktop” branch that’s generated under “This PC”, like this:

[image: Navigation Pane with “Desktop” under “This PC”]

This appears to be unique to Windows 10; I use the same desktop & software setup with Windows 8.1 on my laptop and it’s never done this.

Simply put, this behavior annoys me and I want it to stop. I already have perfectly good desktop folders at the bottom of the NavPane, I don’t want a new set to spontaneously appear elsewhere and take up valuable vertical space for nothing.

Is there a way to prevent this instance of “Desktop” from appearing under “This PC” in the NavPane? I’ve Googled but can’t find any answers. I’ve found some guides for adding or removing certain folders from the NavPane, but not this second “Desktop” specifically. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `Desktop` that appears as the root when `Show all folders` is selected is a virtual folder with namespace junctions to the file system locations.

If you open three **File Explorer** windows:

- Desktop ( namespace root )
- Computer\Desktop
- C:\Users<*UserName*>\Desktop

(my Desktop is pointed to a folder named `DummyDesktop`)

[image]

and then use **PowerShell** to examine the properties of the windows, you'll see that the `Folder` object for all three has the same value for path -- the associated file system folder:

```
PS C:\> @((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).Document.Folder.Self.Path
C:\Users\keith\DummyDesktop
C:\Users\keith\DummyDesktop
C:\Users\keith\DummyDesktop
PS C:\>
```

So it could very well be how the apps are coded. If they're using the path rather than a PIDL, they're quite likely unaware of the namespace distinction.